# The seaborn doesn't display the correct color when I have set the RGB hex code

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn, figure

I have run the following code in the Ubuntu server with Jupyter notebook. I actually want the color to be '#3a923a', but it appears to be '#458745'. Can someone help me?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(dpi=150)
x = ['A','B','C','D']
y = [164, 86, 126, 53]
sns.barplot(x=x, y=y, color='#3a923a')
```

[image]

```py
plt.bar(x, y, color='#3a923a')
```

[image]

Comment: You need `sns.barplot(..., saturation=1)` to avoid that the color gets desaturated.

Comment: All add to @JohanC's comment that it is [documented](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) that the default is `saturation=0.75`.

Comment: Thank you so much@JohanC and @Mark. Your comments really help!